# Loading .hgt file in SAGA GIS

Tags: dem, saga, hgt

I want to display and work with the data from http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version1/Eurasia/
in SAGA-GIS but am having difficulties knowing which module I should use to load the data.

As far as I know hgt files are raw binary data, so this should work with the Import Binary Raw/data but by simply loading the data into the import window, nothing happens meaning I have to define the correct parameters, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "gdal_translate" from GDAL to convert the HGT files for example to GeoTIFF format.

For example:

> gdal_translate N45E009.hgt N45E009.tif

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can open directly in SAGA using gdal. Use modules/file/gdal or just drag and drop the file on saga.